# I am working on Ionic project Compressing and watermarking video in ionic app before uploading it to server

Tags: ionic-framework, ffmpeg, video-compression

I have a large video file in ionic app which need to  be compressed and watermarked before uploading, one of the solution i think is ffmpeg how can i use it? Can someone refer any article Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/rossmartin/video-editor-ionic2

Comment: This is video-editing on ionic 2, codes should be changes by 50% i thing but you should get the point of working from it.

Comment: watermarking is not possible by it. I want my company logo overlay on video I was able to do with ffmpeg(on server side). I am looking for similar solution client side.